# How to get next turning point from google map - (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Currently I am working on an application in which I need to fetch location of next turning point without open any map on phone and then I need to store this location on string array or Hashmap.

Example: Suppose I need to go from Mumbai city to Delhi city. When I run my app it ask for two location `source location` and `destination location` in text box and  give me information on button click in form of text which can be look like this:-
You are here `current location`------> turn left from `turning point location`-----> turn right from `next turning location`----> you reached at `destination location`.

Note- User is not moving any where, he/she get this information in text from on button click. So I need to find turning points (left and right turn) of route.

I am not able to find solution of this on internet.
So how can I do this. Can somebody post working example or give me a link of related example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: still not found any solution ??????